# Xamarin Forms "blank" solution is not building because incorrect monoandroid version is found

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have Xamarin.Forms Visual Studio 2017 solution that is configured :

```
In the Aplication tab
    Target Framework: Android 4.4 (Kit Kat) - 

In the Android Manifest tab
    Minimum Android Version: Android 4.4 (API Level 19 - Kit Kat)
    Target Android Version: Android 4.4 (API Level 19 - Kit Kat)
```

The aplication was created using the "Blank" Xamarin.Forms wizard that is launched from the "File -> New Project" wizard.

When trying to build the solution for the first time I am getting this error and many others that are similar, including sintax errors that I assume are caused of the previous errors

> Error NU1202  Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 27.0.2.1 is not
>   compatible with monoandroid44 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.4). Package
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 27.0.2.1 supports: monoandroid81
>   (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)

[image]

I have tryed installing the Android 4.4 Sdk with the SDK Manager that comes with Visual Studio but problem continues. I have also try to update the NuGet packages of the Android project but that also fails with same errors

**I need my Android App to target API 4.4 an above what do I need to change to achieve this ??**

Comment: You are confusing the three common [Android Version Values](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd). In your case, you want to download and install the latest version of Android, and set your `minSdkVersion` value to the lowest you'd like to support. You are setting your `TargetFrameworkVersion` to KitKat when the libraries dependent on the template require API 27+. Thus `Target Framework >= 27`, `Target Android Version >= 27`, and `Minimum Android Version = Lowest version you'd like to support`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the  minimum to 4.4 and the target version 8.0.  Even though, it will be required if you are planing to upload your app on the playstore:
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk